# React and node cors error from same origin

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi this is my react code i have used to download the file from url my backend server domain is https://example.com:3000 and react server domain is https://example.com.But everytime i am getting error.
I am getting the correct response for all the other apis but only while downloading the file from server i am getting the cors error.I am using apache to serve react application.

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com:3000/uploads/private-79-38/1676275634939-chats.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

React Js Code:

```jsx
<Link to={"#"} className="text-decoration-none">
  <button
    className="dropdown-item "
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
      console.log("called");
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

      fetch(file.file_path, {
        headers: headers,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res);
          return res.blob();
        })
        .then((blob) => {
          console.log(blob);
          const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.download = file.file_real_name;
          console.log(a);
          a.href = href;
          a.click();
          a.href = "";
        });
    }}
  >
    Download
  </button>
</Link>;
```

Nodejs Backend Code :

```js
app.use(cors());
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: `http://` is not the same origin as `https://`. Also, why are you writing your own incomplete and invalid CORS middleware?

Comment: You cannot use `*` origins with `allow-credentials`. You're not even using credentials (cookies) so why have this at all. If you were using the standard `cors()` middleware, it would have told you this in an error message

Comment: @Phil okay i have removed it and used 
```app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'

}));```.   still getting same error.    rest all apis are working only while downloading the file i am getting cors error isssue

Comment: What is the actual response status and body? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel. FYI, GET requests do not require a content-type header when they have no content

Comment: @Phil 79:1 Access to fetch at 'https://example.com:3000/uploads/private-79-38/1676350632672-glimmer-chats%20(1).pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.     Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: That is an error message from the _Console_ panel, not the response itself. Like I said, use the _Network_ panel, click on the request, check the _Response_ tab. Also, [edit] your question to add new data, it does not belong in the comments. Please also update the code to match what you're currently using

Comment: @Phil Failed to load the response data no resource is found with the data with given identifier

Comment: Hi @Phil i have edited as you have suggested can you help me in this please ?